# ajax problem : Undefined index, what should i do plz?

Tags: php, ajax

i'm trying to learn ajax for a new project, i need to upload data using some javascripts variables, so in order to start , i decided to try a small easy ajax problem , but i didnt work,

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\Apache24\htdocs\d.php on line 4 is shown

My .js file :

```
<script>

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'd.php',
    data: {name : "aa"},
    success: function(output) {
        alert(output);
    }
    error: function(request, status, error){
            alert("Error: Could not delete");
    }
);
        </script>
```

My php file:

```
<?php

print_r($_POST['name']);

?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Try `data: {"name" : "aa"}` instead of `data: {name : "aa"}`

Comment: Step 1. Look at the debug console in your browser to see what is being sent. FF is F12. Step 2. Do a var_dump($_REQUEST); to see what is received.

Comment: @bassxzero didnt work..

Comment: You need to run your js file not PHP file. It seems that you are executing your PHP file.

Comment: Open up the Developer console in your browser, then look at the Network tab when you make the request. Check the headers tab to see what exactly is being sent and how.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I'm lunching it with my localhost not by a right click

Comment: @AlaaHachad plz, upload the complet code: html (complete form plus javascript that add files), javascript code and php code on server side, you need open the main file like this: `http://localhost/` if you need a javascript test, you need a html file or php with html embed file, recommend use `index.php` o `index.html`, check if you are executing the javascript using `console.log('excuting script');` and on sever side create a `echo var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: @AlaaHachad  let us know how you are running your ajax code? also check your browser console while running this ajax code and see if any error shown there. if yes, then share with us. But the million dollar question is how's you are running this ajax, because it's not going to trigger automatically

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i wrote your code in my project to understand what was the problem, indeed the code is correct but you were missing a "," and a "}" 
Below you can see the working code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'd.php',
        data: {name : "aa"},
        success: function(output) {
            alert(output);
        },
        error: function(request, status, error){
            alert("Error: Could not delete");
        }
    });
```

Another tips for you, add a check in the .php file :

```
if(isset($_POST)){
   my_data = $_POST['name'];
}
```

have a nice work!

Answer (score -3):

Try this code in javascript.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'd.php',
    data: {name : "aa"},
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
}).then(function(output) {
    alert(output);
}, function(request, status, error){
    alert("Error: Could not delete");
});
```